# Getting byte offsets in msgpack 0.6

Tags: python, msgpack

In my scenario I need to allow random access to single items serialized with msgpack. I.e. given a binary file and an item index, I want to jump to exactly that position in the file and deserialize this item.

To get the byte offset to each item I use the `unpack` function of the `mgspack.Unpacker`. In mgspack 0.5 `unpack` accepts an optional argument `write_bytes` which is a hook that is called on the raw data string before serializing. Counting the `len` of this string gives me the size of the item in bytes, allowing me to accumulate the byte offset.

Since msgpack 0.6 the `write_bytes` argument is not accepted anymore and I didn't find any replacement that gives me the *raw* input string or the number of consumed bytes after reading an item.

Here is the function that I use to create the index. The function returns the index as a list of byte offsets. Each entry `index[i]` contains the byte offset to item `i`. The critical part is the `unpacker.unpack(write_bytes=hook)` call, which does not accept any attributes anymore.

```
def index_from_recording(filename):
    # create empty index
    index = []

    # hook that keeps track of the byte offset of the `msgpack.Unpacker`
    hook = ByteOffsetHook()

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        # create the `msgpack.Unpacker`
        unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(f)
        try:
            while True:
                # add current offset to index
                index.append(hook.offset)

                # unpack (and discard) next item.
                # The `hook` keeps track of the read bytes
                unpacker.unpack(write_bytes=hook)  # <== `write_bytes` not accepted since 0.6
        except msgpack.OutOfData:
            pass

    return index
```

The `ByteOffsetHook` is defined as follows. The hook simply counts the `len` of the raw input string and accumulates it.

```
class ByteOffsetHook(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.offset = 0

    def __call__(self, data):
        self.offset += len(data)
```

For debugging you can use this function to generate a dummy recording.

```
def serialize_dummy_recording(filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for serialized_sample in [msgpack.packb({'x': i}) for i in range(10)]:
            f.write(serialized_sample)


def main():
    filename = "test.rec"
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        serialize_dummy_recording(filename)

    index = index_from_recording(filename)
    print(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the `tell` method is returning the current byte offset of an `Unpacker`. This behavior is however not described in the [latest documentation](https://msgpack-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#msgpack.Unpacker.tell) that I could find. Also the `write_bytes` parameter is not declared as deprecated as mentioned in the [commit](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python/commit/39f8aa78c7bc6b6b18a1c814a0c296f55242f028) where the parameter was removed.

The working function to create the index now looks as follows:

```
def index_from_recording(filename):
    # create empty index
    index = []

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        # create the `msgpack.Unpacker`
        unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(f)
        try:
            while True:
                # add current offset to index
                index.append(unpacker.tell())

                # unpack (and discard) next item
                unpacker.unpack()
        except msgpack.OutOfData:
            pass

    return index
```